# Incorrect answers are being upvoted and accepted

Tags: discussion

Recently I've noticed that there are many answers which partially inaccurate and even just wrong. However these answers are being upvoted by people who probably not very familiar with the topic and think that the answer is good (No one can really be blamed for that but I personally tend not to upvote answers which I am not sure in their correctness). Moreover, some of those answers are even getting accepted. Eventually it creates a very sad picture of a site with questionable reputation.. I understand that this is how it works and there is nothing much to do about that. But it seems that such incorrect\problematic answers should be eventually downgraded by other users but I don't think that there actually ARE enough active users here on this site (AVP) to create this balance.
So, again, there is not much can be done about that but I just thought that maybe some kind of mass review could be organized, just to walk through the recenty questions and answers and see it they seem legit?

What do you guys think?

Comment: If you see an answer that is incorrect, please downvote it and leave a comment.  The comment should help those who don't know better to not blindly upvote.

Comment: A lot of askers seem to accept answers *far* too quickly. Often the first answer posted is accepted before any other answers are posted.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge I completely agree, downvoting without providing any comments missing the whole point.

Comment: @ObscureRobot Exactly! And it seems that once the answer got accepted, it's final and perfect. I rarely see more attempts to answer the questions with accepted answers.. People should be somehow encouraged to wait before accepting any answer.

Comment: Over on SO, even my best answers have been edited at least six times by now. Here, that is much more rare. Might be because of different cultural norms in the A/V world compared to Dev. A/V people seem to be more cautious about stepping on toes, while devs tend to stomp with the force of a thousand stormtroopers.

Comment: @ObscureRobot but the force of 1000 storm troopers is nothing, because they'd all miss you.

Comment: They might not be able to shoot, [but they sure can stomp](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8ZvsFCxxCU).

Answer (score 3):

I personally have had answers on some SE sites that I've written that have had technical errors to begin with (either because I didn't understand the question, or simply because I had some misunderstanding about the topic.)  Comments are the best way to deal with them.  Inform the user (politely) about the error and make sure to post an accurate answer yourself.

Also be sure to check back and reward the user if they fix it (many will).

The much bigger problem is that many question askers on AVP in particular seem to abandon their question or get an initial answer and never revisit it.  Ultimately though, votes matter more than accepted answers.  A bad accepted answer simply means that the person asking the question didn't get the right answer when they thought they did.  Highly voted answers have far more meaning.